# Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 backup error

Tags: sql-server, backup

I'm trying to do a simple backup to an external disk and getting this error:

> Backup failed for Server 'Server-name'

Additional information:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The media loaded on "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL.." is formatted to tsupport 1 media families, but 2 media families are expected according to the backup device specification.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)`

Backup type: Full

Why am I getting this error and why is the message pointing to `C:\Program Files..` if the destination file is an external device?

Comment: Please show your backup command.

Comment: Most likely you added a second destination file by accident?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This error means that you "striped" your backup across multiple files, and you're only providing one of the files when you're trying to restore.

If you're backing up using SQL Server Management Studio, make sure that you click "remove" to remove any existing backup destinations before you "add" the file you want to back up to.

Answer (score -2):

To avoid above error, just replace your new backup location with listed backup locations. Means remove all old entry and add your new backup location. It will work.

Comment: You are correct, but this doesn't improve the existing answer.